# How to draw toolbar tabs in OS X?

Tags: macos

How do I manually draw those toolbar buttons that act as tabs? I mean the control in the top of this window (see below). I think technically they are radiobuttons placed on a toolbar, or at least they evolved from that.

Is there any HITheme* API to draw them? Or do I have to use CoreUI? I tried CUIDraw with `kCUIWidgetButtonSegmentedSCurve`, but that just gives an ordinary segmented toolbar button (like on top of a finder window). What I'm looking for is the "settings tab" version:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use NSToolbar + set of NSToolbarItems with "selectable" property set. This will do the trick.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks a billion times! I thought this was related to the "Autovalidates" option.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is about drawing manually (using HITheme or CoreUI), not using Cocoa.